# How to properly texture Saturn Ring?

Tags: texture, cinema4d

There is the [Saturn ring texture](https://www.solarsystemscope.com/textures/download/2k_saturn_ring_alpha.png)

[image]

how can I properly add this texture on the ring (*thin tube*) in *C4D*?

[image]

Comment: Rotate it on PS and just paste the resulting image into your model.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where your UV for the rings must be different from the UV for the sphere - you want UVs which wrap ***along*** the rings, and *that* way the image you have will be correctly wrapped along the rings too.

For the mysterious downvoter - this is what I mean - and why it is a correct answer.

[image]

Comment: "mysterious downvoter" Funny :o) Here is an upvote, but I do not use Cinema.